# How to create back button in my android application

Tags: android-layout

I'm pretty new to android programming. Anyway, I made a test application with several activities. The app works as following:

Activity 1 = MainMenu, Activity 2 = A2, Activity 3 = A3....

MainMenu->A2->A3->A4->A5....

If a user is at, lets say A4 and presses the physical back button (finish()) he will go back to A3 which is obvious.. But I don't want that. I want the back button to work as a "Back to "MainMenu" button" while in my app. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can override onBackPressed() to do that:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    startActivity(new Intent(mContext, MainMenu.class));
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add an event handler for the back key, and when it pressed you just lunch the main menu intent.

take a look here: 
 http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html?m=1

it has some good code for you to use.